# Conflicting types in some constituents

Tags: typescript, union-types

I'm trying to have a method return a specific type depending on a string given as an argument. This is what I have:

```
interface Base {
    type: 'a' | 'b';
}

interface MyA extends Base {
    type: 'a';
    nameA: string;
}

interface MyB extends Base {
    type: 'b';
    nameB: string;
}

interface Mappings {
    a: MyA;
    b: MyB;
}

const testMethod = <K extends keyof Mappings>(
    type: K
): Mappings[K][] => {
    const values: Mappings[K][] = [];

    if(type === 'a') {
        values.push({
            type: 'a',
            nameA: 'My name a'
        });
    }
    else if(type === 'b') {
        values.push({
            type: 'b',
            nameA: 'My name b'
        });
    }

    return values;
}
```

So if I run `testMethod('a')` it would have a return type of `MyA[]` and when I use `testMethod('b')` it would return `MyB[]`. But no matter what I do I can't get it to work. The errors are always:

> Argument of type 'MyA' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Mappings[K]'.   Type 'MyA' is not assignable to type 'never'.
> The intersection 'MyA & MyB' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.

I thought the array could be the problem but returning a variable of type `Mappings[K]` has the same issue. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChkHJgCeADhAFzIDkc1yAPjQEbUDcuAvrrqJLIhQBZYgEFkEAB6QQAEwxpMOfIRLkqtdioIg4AWwiiqGMFFABzDt17ho8JMhGoJ0iHIXosyPISJlKLFq+ugaoxqYWVjx8doKOcKSkFgo+hHBUIqIcvswZxKhRuAgA9iAmRBAmQhBgABbFssgAvMgAPADSLjLyyADWEMTFMPGJyQB8ABTafurI7bgAlBkJSSDmGADa7QC6G9vNY97TJWVgyABucAA2AK6Vy6Nrmzt7zch7HNPAMBNqKE0Amh0BZHXy+S63SoAOlINwwtQmqTBYL+GjoABppsidPpDBoRMgQig6FjCJwFtkydMIFcvN9fv5moDqKwQUiwRC7hgYXCEezsTMAizqJiBcFcWEaASichWKSCOTKQqeL4oDUblAQBdrlyrEA) is the playground link. I've done a similar thing in the past like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQFclsBZTMOAbwCg565MAuOAbQGcYpkBzAXQDcdBgCMWrJIQC2ItABo4nbkn5CAvjRoA3TFDgQwaTDAQQk7FlTYBrYAE9ESRV158A-C0xI7rQXDVwALzUakI06MTYJmZwwEgAjoTASQA8ANKxIKhIACbscLZ2EOgEkeRgAHwAFDB2hixpCgB0LWC6mFLAqFAWpSTlrGl8AJTUwvQGRtHmrAAGACRUtYZqTIttUB1daOysAAx8arN8QXAbW93s6kA) one to modify a function's argument according to the string given as argument, but here I'm completely lost.

Any guidance or typescript resources I can read would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiously, this worked for me as soon as I specified that Mappings extended `Record<string, MyA | MyB>`. I removed the common ancestor Base as it didn't seem to help.

```js
interface MyA {
    type: 'a';
    nameA: string;
}

interface MyB {
    type: 'b';
    nameB: string;
}

interface Mappings extends Record<string, MyA | MyB> {
    a: MyA;
    b: MyB;
}

// same as above

const arrayOfMyA = testMethod('a');  // typed as MyA[]
const arrayOfMyB = testMethod('b');  // typed as MyB[]
```

I don't have an intuitive explanation, other than that an explicit union is the only way to convince TypeScript that `'a' | 'b'` (`keyof Mappings`) exhaustively results in `MyA | MyB`...despite the fact that `Mappings[keyof Mappings]` correctly results in `MyA | MyB` both before and after the change! This might be a TypeScript bug, or at least an opportunity for an improvement.

```
type MappingResults = Mappings[keyof Mappings];
// typed as MyA | MyB, regardless of whether
// Mappings extends Record<string, MyA | MyB>!
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CCyDeAoZQ5MdABwgC5kByOagbgKJDgFsJMqBnMKUAc0YBfPHlCRYiFBgBCuJoRLkq1AEYMFyFuxndeA4aPHR4SNHFKkBXZBAAekEABMbAJQgIA9lCcAeHnwg-AA0aFjIAD5hMgB88kTIcFQYmIwJqsnoMoZ4XiA8xBA8qBBgABaeTsgAvMi+ANK2DhDONgDWEOieMOaW1jEAFJpKlMj1eACUyRZWQVwA2vUAuvNLNXH4CXkFAG5wADYArkXTfXOLK2u1q4yawDADIzXVtbTUE-EJRHtHRQB0pEOXDKA02X3BIxUdGCmnBhG0HBUGC0bBQdFhRCEEzSmM0EH2XBQ90eZBQL1e6g+YPBP2OXABQJB1LhilJKnUMJZCQRuhoyIRyHUGMIWJxItECSgpUOUBAyFpRRy2zAiSgUDg6AA8jAUjVCsVShUnAM3tjCAB6c3EUlVOA2FKrXKefIquBqjXa2R6yAG8qVE2U+gWq0jW32rKOvBPVAzATuLiHfZgGy1GNnfgLDpdHpp2YZpaMS3W8hhsLYKKyUJS-hupz7Io2brIADuZUN0DwRdz1iajhcyHcXh8-n0QVCuorWRiAEIgA)